# HBase Java API client on Windows without Cygwin?

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, hbase

We have recently started a project to store a load of data on a Hadoop / HBase cluster. I have followed the tutorial in the Apache 'Quick Start' guide, and have got a small standalone HBase instance running successfully on one of our servers. I am able to use HBase shell to create tables, put data, get, scan etc - looks good!

Now my problem: our servers where HBase will be installed are all linux, but all the developers in my company use Windows machines - it would be nice if we didn't have to make everyone in the company install Cygwin just to use the Java API. Currently, when I try to connect running from inside Eclipse with the Java API, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2014-12-05 17:13:05,910 [TESTING] {main} Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
```

Followed eventually by:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to find region for row1 after 0 tries.
```

My question is: is it possible to use the Java API for HBase on Windows, connecting to a server running on Linux, without installing Cygwin, Hadoop and HBase on every developer's machine? Alternatively, would another package such as Kundera be able to connect without Cygwin? If not, how does the REST API compare in performance to the native Java API? I could always write my own wrapper for that and distribute it to our developers (although no doubt something like that may already exist).

Any help on this would be much appreciated as I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer on Google!